# symfony/propel: question about i18nTable and modules generated in the backend

Tags: internationalization, symfony1, propel

in Jobeet there is this part below of the schema:

```
jobeet_category:
  _attributes:  { isI18N: true, i18nTable: jobeet_category_i18n }
  id:           ~

jobeet_category_i18n:
  id:           { type: integer, required: true, primaryKey: true, foreignTable: jobeet_category, foreignReference: id }
  culture:      { isCulture: true, type: varchar, size: 7, required: true, primaryKey: true }
  name:         { type: varchar(255), required: true }
  slug:         { type: varchar(255), required: true }
```

I have created the corresponding modules in the backend, but when i try to create a new "jobeet_category_i18n" i miss the select that would permit choose a "jobeet_category" object.

Anyway i try to create it, but as i expected an error message that speaks about the foreign key is showed.

Is that schema ok? why is not showed the select to choose a "jobeet_category" object?

Javi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/08-Internationalisation-and-Localisation#chapter_08_propel_objects_internationalization